# Unable to get Xdebug to work on VSCode with browser extension

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug

I'm trying to setup Xdebug on my VSCode, to do so I installed the **PHP Debug** extension and set the launch.json as so :

```
{
    "version": "0.2.0",
    "configurations": [
        {
            "name": "Listen for XDebug",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "port": 9000,
            "stopOnEntry": true,
            "pathMappings": {
                "/Users/me/Desktop/www/my_current_project": "${workspaceFolder}"
            }
        },
        {
            "name": "Launch currently open script",
            "type": "php",
            "request": "launch",
            "program": "${file}",
            "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
            "port": 9000
        }
    ]
}
```

For the extension on chrome I use Xdebug helper, and I'm not sure if it's supposed to work without cookie or not in the case of VSCode (because PHPStorm needs one), but I've set the cookie value to "VSCODE" as I found somewhere on the internet...and the extension is enabled (green).

Then, I clicked on "Listen for Xdebug" on VSCode, and set some breakpoints on my script, but VSCode does not respond to me calling the script from the browser.

I have not found so far any solution that worked for me, I guess there's an issue in the launch.json file maybe..

Comment: How do you refer to your PHP server that you want to connect to? As `localhost`, with an IP address, or a DNS name? Temporarily switch off any software firewall. Also post values from the `xdebug.ini` file in `/etc/php/7.4/apache2/conf.d/20-xdebug.ini` (or similar) dir.

Comment: Same issue for both localhost and 127.0.0.1 ; The xdebug.ini file is quite long, I'm not sure what do you want to see in it ?

Comment: So your "remote" host is localhost, not a cloudserver or something. Good. - You can remove the commented lines from the xdebug.ini file, then it is much shorter. - in `xdebug.ini` you can activate logging and you'll get informative output in `/var/tmp/.../tmp/xdebug.log`

Comment: Well thanks it looks like it work with php internal server but not with MAMP.. humm i'll try to figure it out

Comment: @naspy971 1) Please show whole Xdebug section of the `phpinfo()` output captured via browser (since it's a web page debug). 2) Please enable Xdebug log and try to debug. Then share the log file. It will tell where it tries to connect to (if it tries at all) and what the response is.